# onelogin username and email regex

Tags: api, onelogin

Where can I find the username and email requirements/regex on onelogin's docs? I have looked everywhere but cannot find it

Answer (score 0):

In general it is pretty accepting. Although customers can add rules to make their acceptance criteria more strict.

email = [^@\s]+@[a-Z0-9]+.[a-Z0-9]+
this means:
1. one or more characters that aren't the @ sign or whitespace
2. the @ sign
3. one or more characters a-Z or 0-9
4. the period '.'
5. one or more characters a-Z or 0-9

username = .*
this means basically any character but new lines

both must be unique within the customers account though.